# unable to fetch row where index is of type dtype='datetime64[ns]'

Tags: pandas

I have a pandas `main_df` dataframe with `date` as `index`

```
<bound method Index.get_value of DatetimeIndex(['2021-05-11', '2021-05-12','2021-05-13'],
 dtype='datetime64[ns]', name='date', freq=None)>
```

what am trying to do is fetch row based on certain date.

I tried like this
`main_df.loc['2021-05-11']` and it works fine.

But If I  pass a date object its failing

`main_df.loc[datetime.date(2021, 5, 12)]` and its showing `key error`.

The index is `DatetimeIndex` then why its throwing an error if I didn't pass key as string?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reason is `DatetimeIndex` is simplified array of datetimes, so if select vy dates it failed.

So need select by `datetime`s:

```
main_df = pd.DataFrame({'a':range(3)}, 
                        index=pd.to_datetime(['2021-05-11', '2021-05-12','2021-05-13']))
print (main_df)
            a
2021-05-11  0
2021-05-12  1
2021-05-13  2

print (main_df.index)
DatetimeIndex(['2021-05-11', '2021-05-12', '2021-05-13'], dtype='datetime64[ns]', freq=None)

print (main_df.loc[datetime.datetime(2021, 5, 12)])
a    1
Name: 2021-05-12 00:00:00, dtype: int64
```

If need select by dates first convert `datetime`s to `date`s by [`DatetimeIndex.date`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DatetimeIndex.date.html):

```
main_df.index = main_df.index.date
print (main_df.index)
Index([2021-05-11, 2021-05-12, 2021-05-13], dtype='object')

print (main_df.loc[datetime.date(2021, 5, 12)])
a    1
Name: 2021-05-12, dtype: int64
```

If use `string` it use [exact indexing](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/user_guide/timeseries.html#exact-indexing), so pandas select in DatetimeIndex correct way.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation. But the second suggested method is not working. I updated the question with the issue.

Comment: @Abhilash - How is created `<bound method Index.get_value of DatetimeIndex(['2021-05-11', '2021-05-12','2021-05-13'],
 dtype='datetime64[ns]', name='date', freq=None)>` ? It seems missing last `()` after method

Comment: Found the issue. The program I tried to run used dynamically generated data and where there is a missing index it's showing the error. Sorry for the trouble and thank you for the support.